# Given these numbers, find the secret word

Tags: cipher, number-sequence, word-problem, password

My son is 12 years old and his task was to find an English word from these numbers:

```
13; -8; 2; 2; -6; 12; 2; 6; -1; -12
```

where

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18

S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z
19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26
```

I'm currently at work where I have almost asked everyone of my colleagues but no one was able to solve it which is ridiculous because it's made for children, supposed to be solved in minutes I assume.

We have already tried to directly assign the letters to the numbers (`13 = M, 2 = B` etc.), leaving the negative numbers away at first because we had no idea how to treat them. We also thought that negative numbers will go reverse the alphabet, starting with `Z` and going back to `A`.

What is more, we have also tried to find some function / formula that creates this sequence of numbers which may have helped us, but we couldn't find such function either.

Any ideas? This is really frustrating!

Comment: I thought that perhaps each number represented the relative offset from the previous letter, and that was looking possible up to the 12 - but after that was either an error in the sequence, or proof that it was a failed hypothesis.

Comment: Adding 13, then translating using the given table gives ZEOOGYSLA. Using [dcode.fr](https://www.dcode.fr/rot-cipher) to test for any possible rotation ciphers doesn't give anything meaningful.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: I tried the same thing, even trying all rotations of it. No luck. You can get MOUTH out of the end, but that gives `XKCEGAMOUTH`, which seems unlikely.

Comment: (note to past self: *read the things that you type*.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming a mistake in the problem layout, we could get something with some significance:

> MEGAMOUTH, apparently some kind of shark

The error would be

> There should be only one "2" after the "-8"

And with this

> We start from the 13th letter, M, and then just add or substract the number to get the next letter, wich gives:
>  13 -> M
>  -8 = 5 -> E
>  +2 = 7 -> G
>  -6 = 1 -> A
>  +12 = 13 -> M
>  +2 = 15 -> O
>  +6 = 21 -> U
>  -1 = 20 -> T
>  -12 = 8 -> H
>  Hence : Megamouth

Comment: Gah, just beat me to it.

Comment: At last, it's Deusovi's turn to be beaten by mere seconds!

Comment: I'll bet that this is in fact the answer, and that there is in fact the described error.